# Git workflow for Independent Releases on same Code Base

Tags: git, workflow

We are two teams working on the same code base having common git repository. We are following git-flow and merging our feature branches into develop. But, problem arises when we want to release our changes separately. Since we are merging back into develop, our develop contains changes of both team and hence we have dependency on the release. We cannot create release branch from develop and we cannot release our changes until other team changes are tested. In a sense we have to release together. Due to this dependency if one team changes are delayed it affect the other team as well. Is there any other workflow available that can help in this situation?

EDIT: I am looking for alternative workflow other git-flow that can help in the above situation

Comment: Why is there a dependency on your releases between different teams? I take it you are only merging to develop after a feature is completely finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your workflow is that you're merging to develop before a feature is known to be stable. Develop is meant to be a stable branch that houses what are supposed to be finished, working, and tested new features between releases. It sounds to me like what you're doing is working on a feature, merging it to develop, and then making sure that nothing broke on develop. The latter two of these steps need to be swapped.

What you should instead be doing, is making sure that your feature branch is completely working before you merge it to develop. That way, you can release develop with the expectation that at any given time, it is (supposed to be) stable. To do so, make sure that it's upstream of develop by using a command such as:

```
git merge develop
```

or

```
git rebase develop
```

Then, test the feature on your feature branch, make sure it's working, and then when you merge it to develop, develop will be in the exact same state as the branch that you've already tested.